# Mock object with jest and pass via it via method parameter

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, mocking, ag-grid

I'm trying to mock a whole object (ColumnApi from ag-grid) using jest and then pass it via parameter to some function, which calls method "getAllColumns" from ColumnApi. I don't care how the "getAllColumns" works, but I want it to return some specific array of Columns (Column[]). How can I create this object / mock to able to simultaneously:

- pass it via parameter to some function which requires ColumnApi type
- mock return value of one function of this object.

Test:

```
describe("test", () => {
   
    // my fruitless tries to create the mock / object:


    // let columnApi: ColumnApi {};

    // const spyInstance = jest.spyOn(columnApi, "getAllColumns");
    // const mock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=> "abc");

    // jest.mock("@ag-grid-community/core/dist/cjs/columnController/columnApi", () => columnApi);

    // const columnApiSpy = jest.spyOn(ColumnApi, "getAllColumns");
    //
    // jest.mock("./main", () => ({
    //     columnApi: ,
    // }));
    // let columnApiMock: jest.Mock<ColumnApi>;

    const params = {
        columnApi: columnApi,
    }

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await repository.getRows(params);
    });
});
```

"getRows" function from repository:

```
getRows(columnApi: ColumnsApi) {
    
    columnApi.getAllColumns());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was to just create an object with method "getAllFunctions" defined. This can be done with:

```
let columns: Column[] = {};
let columnApi: {
getAllColumns: columns,
}
```

Then I was able to pass the object `columnApi` to the `params` object and pass it to `repository.getRows` method. No mocking / spying required, creating just my own object with types as they were needed was the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to mock the implementation of the spy. And it's probably best to do this in `beforeEach` (so that jest has a change to remove the spy between tests).

```
import columnApi from '@ag-grid-community/core/dist/cjs/columnController/columnApi'

describe('test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(columnApi, 'getAllColumns').mockImplementation(() => "abc")
    await repository.getRows({ columnApi });
  })
})
```

It doesn't matter what `columnApi` is, or how it was imported, the implementation should be replaced.

Comment: I tried this one (as it can be seen in commented out code) - it didn't work, because the type of columnApi was not ColumnApi (I assumed that you wanted to create it with let columnApi: ColumnApi {};) Without having the ColumnApi type I wasn't able to pass it to repository.getRows(...) method